# AEM/Angular: redirection to specific url on condition

Tags: angularjs, aem

I have a component which has an input filed as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="button blue" errorredirection="http:google.com/home" URL? data-url="${is:formatUrl(properties.buttonlink)}" value="${properties.buttonlabel}" 


and the angular directive is:

$scope.directive("URL", [
                         function() {
                           return {
                             restrict: "A",
                             scope:false,
                             link: function($scope, el, attributes, controllers) {
                              $scope.errordirection = attributes.errordirection;

                             }
                           }
                         }
                       ]);



});
```

I want to redirect to different page when a specific error code is passed to this this page. How can I do that ?